# Generating scrollable content without using hard-coded values or calc function

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to setup a page layout using css for a single page application as follows:

- one header that takes 100% width
- Then 3 columns (West, center, east), each having a fixed footer that "sticks" at the bottom of the page/column.

Only the content of the column should be scrollable.

I managed to get those working, but I had to use css `calc` keyword with hard-coded values for headers, which I don't like (css line 33 in the following codepen).

Here is a mock for reference: https://codepen.io/nabbo/pen/JjoORdY

Here is the "best" solution I have so far :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: LightCoral;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#center {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

#west,
#east {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

footer.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: MediumAquamarine;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

div.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* only this should be vertically scrollable */
  height: calc(100% - 90px);
  /* **I WANT TO AVOID THIS : 90 is actually 50px for header and 40px for footer** */
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>Header</header>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="west">
      <div class="content">
        west content
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">West footer</footer>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
      <div class="content">center content</div>
      <footer class="footer">center footer</footer>
    </div>

    <div id="east">
      <div class="content">east content</div>
      <footer class="footer">east footer</footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same behavior without hard-coded "calc" stuffs (that I have to change every time my footers heights change., or line-height, or...)

I have been looking at css flex and css grids (Which I'm not very familiar with) but could not find a suitable solution.

I know I can also calculate this with a bit of JS, but I would prefer having a 100% css solution that would make the code easier to read and maintain.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

For the `main div` columns I used **Grid** and for the `content div` I used **Flexbox**.

```
body {
    margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
    background-color: LightCoral; 
}

#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 250px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100vh;
}

#west,#east {
    background-color: lavender;
}

#center .content {
  background-color: moccasin;
}

#west, #center, #east {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: MediumAquamarine;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me here (unless I missed something).
the footers are not visible unless I scroll (the body or the div#main, I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: LightCoral;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* you have the header height;
                                 no need for overflow: hidden on body element */
}

#center {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: moccasin;
}

#west,
#east {
  flex: 0 0 250px; /* fg, fs, fb; won't grow or shrink beyond 250px */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lavender;
}

footer.footer {
  margin-top: auto; /* pins the footer to the bottom */
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background-color: MediumAquamarine;
}

div.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div id="main">
  <div id="west">
    <div class="content">
      west 1<br />west 2<br />west 3<br />west 4<br />west 5<br />west 6<br />west 7<br />west 8<br />west 9<br />west 10<br />west 11<br />west 12<br />west 13<br />west 14<br />west 15<br />west 16<br />west 17<br />west 18<br />west 19<br />west 20<br
      />west 21<br />west 22<br />west 23<br />west 24<br /> west 25<br />west 26<br />west 27<br />west 28<br />west 29<br />west 30<br />west 31<br />west 32<br />west 33<br />west 34<br />west 35<br />west 36<br />west 37<br />west 38<br />west 39<br
      />west 40<br />west 41<br />west 42<br />west 43<br />west 44<br />west 45<br />west 46<br />west 47<br /> west 48<br />west 49<br />west 50<br />west 51<br />west 52<br />west 53<br />west 54<br />west 55<br />west 56<br />west 57<br />west 58<br
      />west 59<br />west 60<br />west 61<br />west 62<br />west 63<br />west 64<br />west 65<br />west 66<br />west 67<br />west 68<br />west 69<br />west 70<br /> west 71<br />west 72<br />west 73<br />west 74<br />west 75<br />west 76<br />west 77<br
      />west 78<br />west 79<br />west 80<br />west 81<br />west 82<br />west 83<br />west 84<br />west 85<br />west 86<br />west 87<br />west 88<br />west 89<br />west 90<br />west 91<br />west 92<br />west 93<br /> west 94<br />west 95<br />west 96<br
      />west 97<br />west 98<br />west 99<br />west 100
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">West footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <div class="content">center content</div>
    <footer class="footer">center footer</footer>
  </div>

  <div id="east">
    <div class="content">east content</div>
    <footer class="footer">east footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/MB212/pen/GRgOBYj)

Comment: there is still a calc on the div#main
any possibility to avoid that ?

Comment: You set your header element to `height: 50px`. What would the actual height be?

Comment: the height may change in the future, based on what I set in the header.
Also, if I add padding, margin, etc, that may also change the height. In this case, the calc would be incorrect

Comment: A scroll bar is triggered by an overflow condition. For an overflow condition to occur, there needs to be a overflow. How can an overflow occur without a fixed length somewhere along the line?

Comment: *"In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`."* ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: Actually I was hoping that setting the body's height to 100vh would be enough, and then all children would adapt to that.

Comment: That would trigger an overflow on the `body` element, but the nested elements, would just expand inside, with no reason to generate a scrollbar (they have nothing to overflow).